# Assigning a parent to components or making the "object" the super?

Tags: pointers, reference, super

As you've probably guessed, I had a hard time coming up with the Title.

Anyhow;
In Java, when adding X to a JFrame, X has access to the JFrame it has been added to, through the "super" keyword. 
So basically

```
JFrame jf;
Component comp;
...
jf.add(comp);
```

Inside comp:
    super.remove(this);
This code would add `comp` to `jf` and then `comp` would tell `jf` to remove itself from `jf` with the `super` and `this` keyword.

Is it somehow possible to get the `super` into C# code? Pointers, references???

Answer (score 0):

The call

```
super.remove(this);
```

in Java means "call method `remove()` defined in the superclass, and pass this object as `remove`'s parameter".

In C#, [keyword `base`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) is used instead. Assuming that an identical method is defined in the base class, you call it like this:

```
base.Remove(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

What Java calls a super class is called a base class in C#. The `base` keyword functions like the `super` keyword in Java, referencing the base class.

> In Java, when adding X to a JFrame, X has access to the JFrame it has been added to, through the "super" keyword.

The way you describe it would not work in C# and I have my doubts about Java. The functionality you describe does not sound like inheritance at all. Are you sure your example would work in Java?